# NuGet bug: Windows 8 libraries can't be used in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, windows-10, portable-class-library

I just created a Portable Class Library that targets the following platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8
- Windows Phone 8.1

This is its source code:

```
using System;

namespace PclDummy
{
    public class Hello
    {
        public void World()
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This code should not be run!");
        }
    }
}
```

And uploaded it to NuGet [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PclDummy/1.0.0).

Now when I go to Visual Studio and create a new Windows 10 UAP project, and run the following command:

```
Install-Package PclDummy -Version 1.0.0
```

It gives me [the following stack trace](https://gist.github.com/James-Ko/fd8bcdd680cb56ff532a), saying that the library is incompatible with Windows 10.

I don't see how this is possible, given that the Windows 8 and 8.1 APIs are a subset of the Windows 10 UAP APIs.

What can I do to fix this?

---

**Edit:** If it's also relevant, this is the directory structure for the package:

```
\nuget
    \PclDummy.nuspec
    \lib
        \PclDummy.dll
```

Comment: Shouldn't you target Windows10, maybe in a separate version?

Comment: @Luc When I try doing that, Visual Studio just says that "Windows 8 will be targeted because it supports the same subset of APIs," and it ends up targeting Windows 8 again.

Comment: @abatishchev I published the package with 2.8, the Visual Studio package manager says it's using the API v3.